# How to check of a string's first character is a letter or specific symbol in iOS?

Tags: ios, string

I want to detect of my first letter of a string.

I restrict **.**, **-**, **_** and **0-9** user can't enter first in a `UITextField`. But suppose an user entry **abc.4c** and set crosser before **.** and delete abc then the string will be **.4c** & when user click submit button that times its not validate. So how can i check first letter is a letter or specific symbol in my string?

Comment: have you go through https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html

Comment: @iosDev is it possible to remove in all special character and number in string ..? your requirement full fill this.

Comment: @Ilesh : No, my q is different. User can't add number and special character in first when he/she entry but suppose after angry he/she delete the first letter and starts with special char or number . that time i facing problem

Comment: do you want a textfield text to have everything except numbers?

Comment: i faced this problem . so i give u a upvote on your question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced this problem before 1 week :) & i am to able to solve. I share my code please check

```
NSRange textfieldfirstText = [yourtextfield.text rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:0];
NSRange textfieldmatchText = [yourtextfield.text rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet] options:0 range:textfieldfirstText];

 if (textfieldmatchText.location != NSNotFound)
 {
     NSLog(@"checking...");
 }
 else
 {
     NSLog(@"not checking...");
 }
```

Check with this. I think this is working for you.

Comment: Hi SR Nayak. Thanks alots. Its working fine and i solved my problem. So i also give u up vote and accept your answer :)

Comment: Thanks. Enjoy ur coding :)

Comment: i think you need first character should not be . - _ 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 but the above code is not check this

Comment: Hi Bhaskar, My app is reject only for this reason from client. and after implement this client is accept the app after so many times testing

Comment: @BHASKAR : After telling u i checked again and again now with all  . - _ 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9. Where you get error can u explain me. Its working fi9 for me. please can u explain?

Comment: @iOSDev: you got any issue? Ya its working for you? please reply me

Comment: No dude. Its working fine for me. i also check with all special character and number also. what happened with u @BHASKAR ?

Comment: Did you check the Charecter '&' it returns  its not ok. But you can input '&'

Answer (score 2):

```
[@"your_string" characterAtIndex:0];
```

or you could try with regex:

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES[c] %@", @"^[0-9_\.-]"];
BOOL isConformingToRegex = [p evaluateWithObject:@"your_string"];
```

Comment: This is not working dude. Always goes to else part.
            NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES[c] %@", @"regex_string"];
            BOOL isValid = [p evaluateWithObject:emailField.text];
            
            if (isValid)
            {
                printf("valid string...");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Invalid string...");
            }

Comment: Edited my answer. PS: If you're looking for email-like string checking I would suggest this as regex string: (?:[a-z0-9!#$%\\&'*+/=?\\^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%\\&'*+/=?\\^_`{|}~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])

Answer (score 2):

You can use this checking

```
if(textField.text.length>0){
    NSString *newStr = [textField.text substringToIndex:1];
    if ([newStr intValue]>0 || [newStr isEqualToString:@"."] || [newStr isEqualToString:@"0"] || [newStr isEqualToString:@"-"] || [newStr isEqualToString:@"_"]) {
        NSLog(@"First charecter is wrong");
    }
}
```

Comment: my requirement is first character should not be . - _ 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Answer (score 1):

NSString *str = @"%bc%sa";

```
NSCharacterSet *notAllowedChars = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"] invertedSet];

NSString *Strq = [str substringToIndex:1];

BOOL valid = [[Strq stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:notAllowedChars] isEqualToString:@""];
if (valid) {
    // Its a Symbol
}
else
{
    // letter or numbers
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this on that will give you the *first letter* only from the whole string**

```
NSString *codeString;
NSString *firstLetter = [[codeString substringFromIndex:0] substringToIndex:1];

if([firstLetter isEqualToString:@"."])
{
NSLog(@"Wrong character to start with...");
}
```